# Generate a Calander Event or Reminder using QR Code

Tags: qr-code

I want to generate a QR code that will give me a reminder or create an event for n number of days once scanned. For e.g. if I scan the QR today it shoud give me a reminder after 20 days. So regardless of when I scan it, the code should give me a reminder after 20 days.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep an API call when the page loads after the QR Code is scanned. This API can pass the current timestamp + 20 days in the body to a server when the QR code was scanned and you can then set a reminder using a Scheduler like Quartz OR you can store the same in a database which can be pulled eventually.

You can design the code for this or choose to even automate this using an Automation tool which is much faster, efficient & cheaper [checkout](https://automation.quickwork.co/).